# Can't install Spring IDE for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hey everyone I'm having trouble installing the 'Spring IDE' plugin for Eclipse (Version 4.5.2 Mars) and was wondering how to fix this problem.

From my understanding, it appears the require files are missing in order to install the Spring IDE. This is the message I get.

========================================================================
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

- Software being installed: Spring IDE Spring Data Support 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE)
- Missing requirement: Spring IDE Live Beans Graph 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
- From: Spring IDE Spring Data Support 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE)
  To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
- From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE)
  To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph [3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE]

===========================================================================

I'm pretty new to web development and I'd really like to learn how to create web application using spring MVC. Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You are be having a problem with https://eclipse.org/gef/. In your case specifically you have a problem with the [Eclipse Visualization Toolkit](https://eclipse.org/gef/zest/). ("**bundle org.eclipse.zest.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency:**)". These are core libraries used by Spring IDE.

The solution for your problem should be:

1. Remove all Spring IDE libraries that are left around (if possible and only using Eclipse. Go to the file system only if you know exactly what jars you need to remove from the plugin directory.
2. Install [GEF](https://eclipse.org/gef/).
3. Install the [Spring IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-ide).

Answer (score -1):

For a new developer I would highly suggest using eclipse STS "Spring Tool Suite".  It allows you to create Spring MVC - "Spring Boot" applications and get it **up and running very quickly with little effort**.  There's no need to run around and grab up all the different spring plugins. There are a **ton of examples** for every most types of apps you would want to start creating and you can easily import the start and finished versions of the code.  **No need to download and setup tomcat** as it has an embedded tomcat that you can start and restart quickly with a click of a button.  Also, without any config, you can **see your html, js, and css changes instantly** (hot swap) by just saving the file (you dont have to restart the server).

https://spring.io/tools